# LaTeX Tikz Diagram Not Centering On Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am new to LaTex so please excuse me if this is very basic. I have created a graphic using Tikz, and I am unsure how to make it centred on the page. I have tried `\center` and `\begin{centered}` but these do not fix it. As suggested in another question I tried making it a figure, but if anything it has made it worse, pushing it above the text!

I am using `\usepackage{showframe}` to demonstrate the issue, and show that the graphic is wider than the page. Any tips for a newbie like me would mean a lot :)

A screenshot of the document:

[image]

The LaTex used to create it:

```
% ADAPTED FROM:
% Author: Robert Felty
% Source: http://blog.robfelty.com/2007/02/14/pgf-gallery
% Model structure from Rumelhart \& McClelland (1986, p .222)%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{showframe} % To demonstrate issue

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\tikzstyle{information text}=[text badly centered,font=\small,text width=2.6cm]

\section{Simple Neural Network}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
    \foreach \xa / \xb in {1 / 5, 5 / 9}
        \foreach \ya / \yb / \yc in {2 / 3 / 4, 3 / 4 / 2, 4 / 2 / 3}
        {
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\ya);
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\yb);
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\yc);
        }

    \node at (1,1.3)[information text]{...};
    \node at (5,1.3)[information text]{...};
    \node at (9,1.3)[information text]{...};

    \draw[->] (1,0.4) node[below, information text]
        {Input Neurons (Pixels of Image) $\times$ 784} -- (1,1);
    \draw[->] (5,0.4) node[below,information text]
        {Hidden Neurons $\times$ 100} -- (5,1);
    \draw[->] (9,0.4) node[below,information text]
        {Output Neurons (Confidence of each digit) $\times$ 10} -- (9,1); 

    \draw (3,5) node[information text] { Input $\rightarrow$ Hidden Weights };
    \draw (7,5) node[information text] { Hidden $\rightarrow$ Output Weights };

    \foreach \y in {2,3,4} {
        \draw[->] (-0.5,\y) node[left, information text]{} -- (0.7,\y);
        \draw[->] (9.3,\y) node[left, information text]{} -- (10.5,\y);
        \foreach \x in {1,5,9}
        \filldraw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (0.3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The structure of the network.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Add `draw` to the `information text` style, and you'll see where that space comes from.

Comment: Ah ha, that helps alot. Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is just that you've added some empty nodes on the left side of the diagram that are not visible in the output, but which do influence the bounding box. If you add `draw` to the `information text` style, you will get this output:

[image]

Note the three empty boxes on the left side. Those are made in the `\foreach` loop, so to remove them, modify the first two lines in the loop to

```
\draw[->] (-0.5,\y)  -- (0.7,\y);
\draw[->] (9.3,\y) -- (10.5,\y);
```

i.e. remove the `node[left,information text] {}`.

After that, add `\centering` right after `\begin{figure}`, to get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{showframe} % To demonstrate issue

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\tikzset{information text/.style={text badly centered,font=\small,text width=2.6cm}}

\section{Simple Neural Network}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
    \foreach \xa / \xb in {1 / 5, 5 / 9}
        \foreach \ya / \yb / \yc in {2 / 3 / 4, 3 / 4 / 2, 4 / 2 / 3}
        {
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\ya);
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\yb);
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\yc);
        }

    \node at (1,1.3)[information text]{...};
    \node at (5,1.3)[information text]{...};
    \node at (9,1.3)[information text]{...};

    \draw[->] (1,0.4) node[below, information text]
        {Input Neurons (Pixels of Image) $\times$ 784} -- (1,1);
    \draw[->] (5,0.4) node[below,information text]
        {Hidden Neurons $\times$ 100} -- (5,1);
    \draw[->] (9,0.4) node[below,information text]
        {Output Neurons (Confidence of each digit) $\times$ 10} -- (9,1); 

    \draw (3,5) node[information text] { Input $\rightarrow$ Hidden Weights };
    \draw (7,5) node[information text] { Hidden $\rightarrow$ Output Weights };

    \foreach \y in {2,3,4} {
        \draw[->] (-0.5,\y)  -- (0.7,\y);
        \draw[->] (9.3,\y) -- (10.5,\y);
        \foreach \x in {1,5,9}
        \filldraw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (0.3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The structure of the network.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey. I "worked" parallel on the question. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Thanks again. Serves me right for trying to adapt code above my level!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your picture is not symmetric to it's own center. I used `\framebox` to visualize the border of the `tikzpicture`.

[image]

```
% ADAPTED FROM:
% Author: Robert Felty
% Source: http://blog.robfelty.com/2007/02/14/pgf-gallery
% Model structure from Rumelhart \& McClelland (1986, p .222)%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{showframe} % To demonstrate issue

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\tikzstyle{information text}=[text badly centered,font=\small,text width=2.6cm]

\section{Simple Neural Network}

\begin{figure}
\centering % <------------------- Added
\framebox{ % <------------------- Added
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
    \foreach \xa / \xb in {1 / 5, 5 / 9}
        \foreach \ya / \yb / \yc in {2 / 3 / 4, 3 / 4 / 2, 4 / 2 / 3}
        {
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\ya);
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\yb);
            \draw (\xa,\ya) -- (\xb,\yc);
        }

    \node at (1,1.3)[information text]{...};
    \node at (5,1.3)[information text]{...};
    \node at (9,1.3)[information text]{...};

    \draw[->] (1,0.4) node[below, information text]
        {Input Neurons (Pixels of Image) $\times$ 784} -- (1,1);
    \draw[->] (5,0.4) node[below,information text]
        {Hidden Neurons $\times$ 100} -- (5,1);
    \draw[->] (9,0.4) node[below,information text]
        {Output Neurons (Confidence of each digit) $\times$ 10} -- (9,1); 

    \draw (3,5) node[information text] { Input $\rightarrow$ Hidden Weights };
    \draw (7,5) node[information text] { Hidden $\rightarrow$ Output Weights };

    \foreach \y in {2,3,4} {
        \draw[->] (-0.5,\y) node[left, information text]{} -- (0.7,\y);
        \draw[->] (9.3,\y) node[left, information text]{} -- (10.5,\y);
        \foreach \x in {1,5,9}
        \filldraw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (0.3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
} % <------------------- Added
\caption{The structure of the network.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Edit

Following the advice of [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) (adding `draw`) you see additional empty boxes that occupy space.

```
\tikzstyle{information text}=[text badly centered,font=\small,text width=2.6cm,draw]
```

[image]

Comment: Use \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,shadows,shapes} and use \centering. It works for me.